# Root from Database to OS

Tags: penetration-test, privilege-escalation

One of my friends rents a VPS on which he runs around 20 websites, some of them for small businesses. He has been having some security issues and has asked me to help assess the vulnerability of his box (I'm just an undergraduate interested in infosec).

I have managed to gain root on the MariaDB database, and am now attempting to get root on the box itself. From what I see, most of the sites run Wordpress, so I figure I can inject some php in a page to print the content of /etc/shadow and from there I can crack the passwords.

My question is **is there a better way to pivot from root on the database to root on the box**?

Comment: root in the DB != root on the box, unless the database is running as root.  Also, PHP shouldn't be able to read /etc/shadow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database and web service should be running with their own privilege sets, if configured correctly. So, it might not be possible from a binary point of view. Database access gets you data access, though, which usually means credentials. Mine the database for creds that might point to entry vectors.

This is what I would do: try loading a PHP shell (many to chose from) in the db and see what is possible from there. You might find a misconfiguration, or a vulnerability to exploit in order to escalate your privileges.

Cracking passwords can take a long time. PHP shell to vuln to escalation can be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

From the DB try to get a shell or at command execution. From there you can poke around the whole file system and OS to try to find a way to elevate to root, assuming the DBMS is not running as root.

Since your friend rents the VPS it might be better to just review the configurations and setup and provide input based on that. But trying to get root is fun, so maybe do both. If you get root you can then look at all the configuration and setup to review it.